# Assemble and disassemble email for spam protection

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

In our `footer` we have an `email` that we are pulling from the database, in `php blade` it will look like this:

```
<a href="mailto:{{ $email }}">{{ $email }}</a>
```

I need to protect him from spambots.

I heard that in `php` it can be split and then assembled through a `javascript`, and it will look something like this:

```
<a href="" data-first="" deta-second="">{{ $email }}</a>
```

Where `data` is the parts of the email itself. But I didn't understand how to separate it and then collect it. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Or tell me similar features, how to protect against spambots.

Answer (score 0):

there are nothing to do with PHP with that as PHP is a server-side language.

you can do this with Javascript ( will use jquery here to simplify it )

this will append the email which is stored in `data-mail` to the `href` attribute and once your client clicks it the attribute will be removed again.

```
<a class="email" data-mail="{{ $email }}">{{ $email }}</a>

$('.email').click(function () {
    let t = $(this);

    t.attr('href', 'mailto:' + t.data('mail'));

    setTimeout(() => t.removeAttr('href'), 1);
});
```

Comment: and besides the click there are other options for protection? allow to pull the email data, add some symbols there and hide them through javasript

Comment: As long as your page has email as plain text in response it's easily to scrape it. This will only protect against simplest kind of bots

Comment: @Kim2000 spam protecting depends on the kind of spam. does they clicks on your webpage? does they scrap it? does they copy it for once and use it multiple times?

Comment: @hassan while there is no spam, this is for the future, to prevent it, so to speak, I am looking for the best way

Comment: @Kim2000 as you are looking for the best way to protect yourself from spam , on the other side they are doing their best to spam you. they won't stop that , so my advice is to go further and when you get a spammers try to deal with them

Comment: @hassan I now get an email from the database `{{ $email }}`, how can I pull it off on the php blade page so that I can edit or split

Answer (score 0):

**Web scrapers will usually only download plain HTML response.**

In this case you will be protected as long as your code doesn't contain email as plain text and email is put back together `onload`

**Some might even execute JS when scraping your page.**

To avoid this you can require user to press something to put email together.
I made a quick example:

```js
function showEmail (element) {
    const infoData = document.querySelector('[data-target="'+element.id+'"]').dataset;
    const mail = infoData.p1 + '@' + infoData.p2 + "." + infoData.p3;
    element.href = "mailto:"  + mail;
    element.text = mail;
}
```

```html
<a href="" id="mailOutput1" onclick="showEmail(this)">Send Email</a>
<!--p1, p2, p3 are filled in PHP -->
<span data-target="mailOutput1" data-p1="john.doe" data-p2="example" data-p3="com"></span>
```

Comment: I now get an email from the database `{{ $email }}`, how can I pull it off on the php blade page so that I can edit or split